# What is the scope of signals?

Tags: c, linux, scope, signals

What is the scope of a signal after I install it??

For example if I have in a function called A this code:

```
sa.sa_handler = &handle_manager_bd;
sa.sa_flags = SA_NODEFER | SA_RESTART; 
sigemptyset(&my_mask);    
sa.sa_mask = my_mask;   
sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
```

If after this i call B, which is another function in the same program, that process will get the signal and do the action specified by `handle_manager_bd` right??

Another example which i would like to understand is as follows: if I have installed the handler in a function A like before and after that I call a function C, which is contained in a header file like `"c.h"` included by the program which contains A with `#include "c.h"`, if I don't install the signal handler in the function C the signal will be recognized because i already installed it in A or should i put again the code above in the function C like i did for A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signals have process scope. Once you install a handler it remains in effect until either

- you remove it with another call to `sigaction`
- the handler gets called and the `SA_RESETHAND` flag is set